# R "Userfriendlyscience" Package

Tags: r, package

I am having trouble loading the userfriendlyscience package in R. I am able to load other packages without a problem but this one is giving me the error:

> Warning in install.packages : error 1 in extracting from zip file
>   Warning in install.packages : cannot open compressed file
>   'BH/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory' Error in
>   install.packages : cannot open the connection

Not sure how to resolve the issue.

Comment: It works for me. Have you tried `install.packages("userfriendlyscience")`?

Comment: Yes I have tried this. I still get the error message I mentioned above

Comment: Could you donwload and re-install the `BH` package to see if it helps?

Comment: So I was able to download and load the BH package. I was then able to download the userfriendlyscience package but was not able to load using the command: library(userfriendlyscience). I get the following error: Error : object ‘read_xls’ is not exported by 'namespace:readxl'
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘userfriendlyscience’ was built under R version 3.3.3 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘userfriendlyscience’

Comment: I just installed it on Windows under RStudio with no seeming problems. It installed five other packages along the way. Used "install.packages("userfriendlyscience").  But when I actually ran library(userfriendlyscience) there were four or five packages it could not find, and I had to install them.  I tried ", dependencies = TRUE" by the way but that did not obviate the need for manually loading the other packages.